# ckeditor skip size for zk

Tags: ckeditor, size, zk

i want to use component ckeditor with ZK.
The component is correctly visible but width/height set are non considered.

I've reproduced the problem using ckeditor on zul as follow:

```
<zk>
    <window id="myId">
        <div width="500px" height="500px" style="background:red">
            <ckeditor id="myEditor" width="500px" height="300px"
                        customConfigurationsPath="/j/ckeditor_cfg_ro.js" toolbar="MyToolbar">
            </ckeditor>
        </div>
    </window>   
</zk>
```

when i open it, the ckeditor is smaller than expected... 
version of ckeditor is 3.6.4.

how i can show my editor in the correct size?

here how the ckeditor is shown:

[image: size is different than expected...]

another info:
the toolbar (configured on file ckeditor_cfg.js on "js" directory) is not shown and using firebug i get the following error:

TypeError: jq(...).ckeditor is not a function
on line: ckez.wpd (line 42564) --> jq(this.$n('cnt')).ckeditor(function(){

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, after some testing in fiddle, the height does work.
The problem is that the height is set for the `textbox` of the ckeditor and do not look at the header.

You can Always create a bug report for it.

[Check this fiddle for it.](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/1lvlb1l/53-ckeditor-startup-with-source-mode)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've checked your fiddle and it work correctly as expected but in my case (see the image attached in the updated question) the size is wrong... maybe i use an old component... don't really know what can be the problem

Comment: I'll check later, going away for 2 days now.

Comment: when you drop the `customConfigurationsPath` and `toolbar` you still have same problem?

Comment: i just found the problem... there was a problem with jquery (it was used a worng version); for this reason... thank you for your information